# Any way to change default ActionVerb for .NET MVC WebApi actions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

According to [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection), in the section of **Action Selection**, it states:

> 3. If none of the above, the method supports POST.

Is there any way to change this default behavior to use HttpGet as default ActionVerb for actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you linked references an `IHttpActionSelector.SelectAction` method being the source of action selection, and a `ApiControllerActionSelector` being the default implementation.

If you look at [the source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack), you can see [the default implementation of that interface](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/62d0b2df0bcca848a8e0848fd1866928df15528e/src/System.Web.Http/Services/DefaultServices.cs#L122) is indeed the  `ApiControllerActionSelector` class. If you look at that `ApiControllerActionSelector` implementation, you can see [it creates a `ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/62d0b2df0bcca848a8e0848fd1866928df15528e/src/System.Web.Http/Controllers/ApiControllerActionSelector.cs#L127) for each method it considers a valid route. Then, when you look at the `ReflectedHttpActionMethod`, [you can see how the default of POST is applied](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/62d0b2df0bcca848a8e0848fd1866928df15528e/src/System.Web.Http/Controllers/ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.cs#L298) when all of the other documented strategies to identify an alternative verb fail.

So, to answer your question, you can write a new `IHttpActionSelector` implementation that returns an `HttpActionDescriptor` which uses different default behavior than that which you can find in `ApiControllerActionSelector`.

Alternatively, you can apply the `[HttpGet]` attribute and/or name the action with a "Get" prefix and call it a day.